# Receiving touch events outside of custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, events, touch

I am developing a custom user control in WPF and trying to receive all touch events OUTSIDE of my control (so I can implement "cancel touches", where the user cancels an action by tapping somewhere else). Is there any good way to do this? Obviously, if I use TouchDown or other events I will only get notified of touches inside my control.

I tried receiving `PreviewTouchDown` events from `Application.Current.MainWindow`, but besides the fact it feels kind of dirty it also doesn't work that well - as soon as I capture those events, the `SurfaceListBox` inside my custom control stops working (it does not recognize touches anymore).

Is there a good way to solve this? Receiving simply ALL touch events would be sufficient as well, I can then check if they are inside my control.

Answer (score 1):

In WPF, events travel the tree of elements. Events starting with "Preview" are the ones that travel up to bottom, meaning from the parent to the elements it contains. In your case, TouchDown event will travel from the control in which it originates and then it will bubble up towards the parents. PreviewTouchDown will travel in the opposite direction: from the parent towards the control.
Your idea of handling PreviewTouchDown event in the Application.Current.MainWindow is a good one and should handle all PreviewTouchDown events, if this is what you want. But in your case, if you want to check if the event originates in your custom control, you should catch all the TouchDown events in your MainWindow and check their Source property, like this:

```
private void CommonClickHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  FrameworkElement feSource = e.Source as FrameworkElement;
  if(feSource.Name == "MyCustomControlName")
  {
      //cancel whatever you want to cancel
      e.Handled=true;
  }
}
```

Do not catch the PreviewTouchDown event as this one will first pop in the MainWindow and just later will go all the way to your control.
[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx) msdn link should give you more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx